# How to fix error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: php, laravel, nusoap

I want to get Token from wsdl external api. I use nusoap_client to do this. But when I debug using `dd($error);`, i got an error like this `HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 35: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`.

How to fix this error in nusoap_client?

This is my function code :

```
public function testapi(Request $request){
    $url = 'https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/services/SecurityProvider?wsdl';
    $client = new \nusoap_client($url, 'wsdl');
    $operation = 'SecurityProviderAuthenticateRequest';
    $params = array(
        'name' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password'
        );
    $hasil1 = $client->call($operation, $params);
    $error = $client->getError();
    dd($error);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx` try using `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx`. Change https to http

Comment: @Regolith, I have changed https to http, may be work, but I got an error like this `HTTP Error: cURL ERROR: 28: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received<br>`